# How do I retrieve a user's LogIn name through the Created By column of a specific item in a document library

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part, login

Created By Field Returns the following:

```
1073741823;#System Account
```

I want the following without string manipulation (i.e. without using substring to remove all of the characters before "`;#`"):

```
System Account
```

How can I do the above programmatically in a visual webpart?

```
string Author = item["Created By"].ToString();
```

The above is what I am currently using to get the author, but I want the login name to be the author

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

I am fairly new to SharePoint and could really use the assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, item["Created By"].ToString());
string Author = userValue.LookupValue;
```